# Finding the amount of nodes for each depth in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, nodes

im wondering how do i find the amount of nodes per depth?

I have a max depth code that looks like this

```
int maxDepth(BinNode n) {
    if (n == null) {
        return (0);
    } else {
        // compute the depth of each subtree
        int leftDepth = maxDepth(n.venstre);
        int rightDepth = maxDepth(n.hoyre);
        // use the larger one
        if (leftDepth > rightDepth ){
            return (leftDepth + 1);
        }
        else{
            return (rightDepth + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

What i want is a code that can count amount of nodes there is for each depth level.

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. You can ask for help though with the code that you have written if you have a problem with it. Be clear what the problem is: what did you expect to happen, and what actually happened. And post the code as an [mcve].

Answer (score -2):

I had such a task in my university class. [Full Code](https://github.com/GoneUp/Studies/blob/master/Semester2/Prog2/Aufgabe10/src/aufgabe10/BinarySearchTree.java#L150)
It saves the count for each level in a hashmap and computes some statistics afterwards.

```
private int maxDepth;
private int sum;
private Map<Integer, Integer> map;

public void statistik() {
    maxDepth = 0;
    sum = 0;
    map = new HashMap<>();
    statistikR(root, 0);

    System.out.println("max:" + maxDepth);
    System.out.println("sum:" + sum);
    double average = 0;
    for (int key : map.keySet()) {
        // key = level, value = count per level
        average += (key * map.get(key));
    }
    System.out.printf("avg: %.2f%n", (average / sum));

}

private void statistikR(Node p, int depth) {
    if (p != null) {
        ++sum;
        if (depth > maxDepth)
            maxDepth = depth;

        if (!map.containsKey(depth))
            map.put(depth, 0);
        int countPerLevel = map.get(depth).intValue();
        map.put(depth, ++countPerLevel);

        ++depth;

        statistikR(p.left, depth);
        statistikR(p.right, depth);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I would have used an `ArrayList<Integer>` rather than a map. Anyway, either works fine.

Comment: Please don't encourage lazy questions by answering them.